# Why does this prolog rule using include/3 evaluate to false, but not when exploding it into individual comparisons?

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I have a prolog rule `position_that_is_equals_to_two` that sets `X` to the position at which the number `2` was found in the provided list of three elements `[X, Y, Z]`:

```
position_that_is_equals_to_two([X, Y, Z], X) :-
    include(==(2), [X, Y, Z], AllElementsWhichHaveAValueOfTwo),
    nth0(0, AllElementsWhichHaveAValueOfTwo, X).
```

When querying it, I immediately get `false`:

```
?- position_that_is_equals_to_two([X, _, _], X)
false
```

However, when I replace [include/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=include/3) with individual comparisons, prolog gives three possible values for `X`, which is the output I would expect:

```
position_that_is_equals_to_two([X, Y, Z], X) :-
    (
        (   X == 2 ; X #= 1)
    ;   (   Y == 2 ; X #= 2)
    ;   (   Z == 2 ; X #= 3)
    ).
```

Querying it:

```
?- position_that_is_equals_to_two([X, _, _], X)
X = 1
X = 2
X = 3
```

Why is the first variant returning `false`? How can it me modified to (1) still use `include` and (2) list possible values for `X`, like the second variant does?

Comment: Why do you mix constraints (i.e. #=) and builtins (i.e. include/3, ==, etc) ?

Comment: @CapelliC I was under the impression that it was ok to mix constraints and builtins. Is it not? Does it "break" prolog's constraint propagation?

Comment: @nich clpfd uses attributed variables, to hint e.g. "this is an integer between 1 and 5, but doesn't have an *actual* value yet". Using that with `==` which checks an actual value, is unwise (i.e. might be logically wrong). Instead, consistently use clpfd's comparisions, as listed at https://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html

Comment: **Both** `include/3` and `(==)/2` are incompatible with `clpfd`.

Comment: @false does that mean that only clpfd operators and clpfd predicates (https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd-predicate-index) can be used when writing clpfd prolog?

What determines if a predicate is clpfd-compatible? Should I look at the constraint source code itself to ensure it does not make use of non-clpfd operators (`==`, `=<`, etc.) and constraints?

Comment: @nich: that is a question of its own. Not so easy to fit into a comment.

Comment: @false Gotcha. I've asked the question on its own here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75074899/which-operators-and-predicates-can-be-used-with-clpfd Thank you!

Comment: `include/3` doesn't *have* to be incompatible with clpfd - depends whether the Goal handles clpfd variables using clpfd-safe constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can it be modified to still use include?

It can't. Include shrinks the original list and throws away information you need to answer the question. With `AllElementsWhichHaveAValueOfTwo = [2]` what is the index of that two? Was it 0, 1, 2 or 50,000? You can't know.

Worse, [include/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=include/3) has the signature `include(:Goal, +List1, ?List2)` and the + means the List1 must be provided, you can't give it unground variables like [X,Y,Z] and have it fill them in. So it can't be used for that reason also.

---

Take this query:

```
?- position_that_is_equals_to_two([X, _, _], X)
```

What you expect out of it is that X in the list has value two and X as the index has value zero. You want `2 = 0`. That can't work.

---

Your other code is giving the right answer for the wrong reasons; the code `(X == 2 ; X #= 1)` says "variable X must be two OR variable X must be one" which is allowed but for your indexing you need them both at the same time, not either/or. What you want it to say is "first list item must be two AND the index must be one".

Change the code to `(X = 2, X = 1)` which is logically how it should be and you're back to asking for 2 = 1 which can't work.

Comment: *variable X must be two OR variable X must be one* it rather say `X` must be instantiated to 2 or `X` must be unifiable modulo constraints with 1. So also `X = 1+0` will lead to success.

Answer (score 2):

In your example code, `X` is being used for 2 different purposes and values - that's a conflict.

`==` is not [clpfd](https://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html).

Looks like this would be sufficient (without using clpfd):

```
pos_2(Pos, L) :-
    length(L, 3),
    nth1(Pos, L, 2).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- pos_2(Pos, L).
Pos = 1,
L = [2, _, _] ;
Pos = 2,
L = [_, 2, _] ;
Pos = 3,
L = [_, _, 2].
```